# Can I specify an order value relative to current order position with CSS order property?

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to know if I can specify an order relative to the current element's order position using CSS order property on a CSS Grid container. For example, if I have divs 1 2 **3** 4 5 6 7 8 I would like to move element #3 after element #5 so the final order is 1 2 4 5 **3** 6 7 8.

Something like (just wondering):

```
div.3 {
  order: current + 2;
}
```

Comment: No...you can't. CSS works on selectors. It has no idea of **current property values**.

Comment: Note that `order` is undetermined until applied (essentially the default value is `0/auto`). If you applied a number (say 2) to `div.3` it will push it to the **end** not back two places.

Comment: I suspect that this is an XY problem. If you can explain *why* this is required, we might be able to assist further.

Comment: Would flexbox solve your needs?

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not sure you can say that. For example calc() and a lot of filter functions e.g. brightness() works by manipulating the current state of the selector target.